# Are there free OpenFX plugins available?

Tags: editing, plugins, production

I read that Sony Vegas Movie Studio (the non-pro version) supports video and audio effect plugins via the OpenFX standard.
Are there any such plugins available as freeware or open-source?

So far I only found commercial pulgins, which are tailored for a professional audience and are beyond my budget as a hobbyist filmmaker.